# Extend or create new swap file

Tags: kubuntu, swap

I have a kubuntu installation (Kubuntu 21.04), which during install created a swap file of 1Gb.
Tryed to create a swap file of 4GB, using the following commands:

```
$ sudo -s
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=4
# chown root:root /swapfile
# chmod 600 /swapfile
# ls -lh /swapfile
# mkswap /swapfile
# swapon /swapfile
# echo '/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

And after it was like there was no swap, and my system had to be repaired (used a repair disk).
Kubuntu is installed in an encrypted lvm2pv partition,(/dev/kubuntu-vg). Inside it there are /dev/kubuntu-vg/root mounted at / and /dev/kubuntu-vg/swap_1 ).

Should I try again and how to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: swap files have to be contiguous, else the swapper gets confused.

Comment: I'm not 1000% sure that you can use a /swapfile on an encrypted lvm. You may have to create a small swap partition on disk and then edit your /etc/fstab, or enlarge your /dev/kubuntu-vg/swap_1 and re-edit your /etc/fstab.

Comment: @heynnema I can see with KDE partitionmanager, that swap file is inside encrypted volume. That means it is created , used encrypted and deleted after poweroff (??). I thought of creating a swap partition instead, but I am afraid of resizing an encrypted partition with all my data inside.

Comment: The swap_1 partition (which is different than the /swapfile that you created) has no real data in it, and can be resized/extended using lvm commands. You should back out your /swapfile and the mods to /etc/fstab and work on extending swap_1 if you can. Show me `swapon -s` and `free -h`.

Comment: @heynnema thanks for your support.   $ swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-2                               partition       999420  9508    -2

Comment: Yes. Back out your /swapfile and /etc/fstab changes. In terminal do "apropos lvm" and you'll see a resize command there, then do "man resize_command_name" for instructions. Report back later.

Comment: @heynema I did as you proposed. I extended swap_1 partition and it was Ok. It helped me because initially thought it was a swap file. I will try later creating a swap file on my older laptop.

Answer (score 1):

### I'm scared of dd, I use fallocate

- Create the swap file:

  `sudo fallocate -l XG /swapfile`

  Where X is the swapfile size in GB

  ```
  sudo mkswap /swapfile
  sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile
  sudo swapon /swapfile
  ```
- Reboot:

  ```
  sudo reboot
  ```
- There is a slight possibility of getting holes in a swapfile when creating it with fallocate. /var/log/syslog can be searched for the phrase `swapon: swapfile has holes` to ensure there will be no data loss.